# Install GDrive on Seagate Central Linux

Tags: linux, nas

Is there a way to install Google Drive for  MontaVista Linux 6?
I have [Seagate Central NAS](http://www.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/home-entertainment/media-sharing-devices/seagate-central/) and it does not have option to sync with GDrive through the standard interface.  It has embedded

```
Linux version 2.6.35.13-cavm1.whitney-econa.whitney-econa (cirrus@cirrus64-development-system) (gcc version 4.4.1 (arm-cavm-64k-2010q1) armv6l GNU/Linux.
```

I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544646/how-to-install-google-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I have root access to the device. But it does not allow me to use `sudo` command to install required repository. See output below:

```
Seagate:~$ su
Seagate:/Data/ginunicyb# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sh: sudo: not found
Seagate:/Data/ginunicyb#
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are trying to install [Grive](https://github.com/Grive), not [GDrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive).
2. You are doing it from an obsolete repo with old binary that doesn't work with Google Drive REST API.
3. If you already switched to `root` with `su`, why are you trying to run the command with `sudo` ?
4. Does your OS have `apt` package manager?
5. If so, read [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html) and install the correct version of Grive2 with the following commands:

Enter one by one:

```
su
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
apt-get update
apt-get install grive
```

After `su` you may be prompted to insert root password.

Comment: It seems that my OS does not have APT Seagate:/Data/ginunicyb# add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 sh: add-apt-repository: not found How I can install it?